# psql generated by default identity and sequences names

Tags: postgresql, psql, identity

my question is simple
what is the current value for the identity and how to retrieve it's sequence name

```sql
CREATE TABlE x(
          id int2 generated by default as identity
          (start 5) 
           primary key,
           name varchar(5))
```

Comment: you can state the new generated sequence name reference 
e.g id int2 generated always as identity (sequence name your_reference_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here [Info functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html):

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence ('x', 'id' );

 pg_get_serial_sequence     
--------------------------------
 <some_seq_name>


--Then

Select * from <some_seq_name>;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can query `pg_get_serial_sequence` with the table and column names:

```sql
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.x','id');
```

Answer (score 0):

on prompt you can \ds is there a better way